# Register scripting language with browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, programming-languages, client-side-scripting

Do any browser vendors support the use of any scripting languages besides

- `text/javascript`
- `text/vbscript` (IE only)

for example:

- `text/lua`
- `text/cs-script`
- `text/php`
- `text/tcl`

If i wanted to use another scripting language in a browser:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   ...some JavaScript...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/vbscript">
   ...some vbscript...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/perl">
   ...some Perl Script...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/php">
   ...some Php...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/tcl">
   ...some Tcl...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/lua">
   ...some Lua...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/pascalscript">
   ...some PascalScript...
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type="text/cs">
   ...some C#...
</SCRIPT>
```

could i?

Is there a way to register 3rd party scripting engines with any browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, Internet Explorer *can* use any script language which provides an [`IActiveScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky29ffxd%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) implementation, and I've seen implementations of both PERL (from ActiveState) and TCL running clientside in IE.

But to minitech's point, this isn't something that would work across browsers, and frankly it's a terrible idea in almost all circumstances.

Comment: There is a browser that does it, with a mechanism for it. Accepted answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you want to use a different language, your best bet is using something that compiles into JavaScript (eg Pyjamas for Python).

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has a native code plugin, allowing the use of any language for which you have the correct plugin. For example, there is a [Tcl implementation](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/14/tcl_on_native_client/) for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is now ***`brython`*** to run `python 3` programs:

see [www.brython.info](http://www.brython.info/)

Impressive work!

seem work across many browsers (I don't have IE)

... still waiting for a `perl` port...

Answer (score 1):

There are what I consider hack-ish ways to do it which involves some kind of interpreter between the browser and the script language. Two examples of this are using [SilverLight to interface with various dynamic languages](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/dynamic-languages/), or [JRuby to interface using Ruby script](http://almaer.com/blog/running-ruby-in-the-browser-via-script-typetextruby). Otherwise it has to get compiled to JS.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Not any portable way, at least, and not anything you should do.